# Dynamically reorded divs based on content size

Tags: javascript, html

I have some divs that when the page loads are populated with images of varying size (these change each time the page loads). I have the divs floating in an attempt to maximize usage of page space. But say if there is a small image first then a large image second then another small image third I would like to be able to float the third image up next to the first image because they can fit next to each other on the page.

Basically im looking for some javascript (JQuery is overkill for the code base I have) to be able to specify the order of the divs or even better for the script to figure out the best placement of the pictures itself

EDIT: Just some more clarification the images are generated server-side using PHP-GD, 1 at a time with a call to  which will return these dynamically generated images with in the divs. no hopefully with the ascii below I can show what I'm getting and what I would like to achieve

So at the moment my images load and float in the order they are listed in html (And i can't prearrange them because the size of the images change each time and I might get all small/large ones that float correctly or something like below):

```
| ---------           |
| |       |           |
| |       |           |
| |       |           |
| ---------           |
| ------------------- |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| ------------------- |
| ---------           |
| |       |           |
| |       |           |
| |       |           | 
| ---------           |
```

What I would like to achieve dynamically or with some sort of sorting code once the images have loaded and i know their widths/heights is the below having started with the arrangement above:

```
| --------- --------- |
| |       | |       | |
| |       | |       | |
| |       | |       | |
| --------- --------- |
| ------------------- |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| |                 | |
| ------------------- |
```

Comment: Are you pulling images from a database to generate the page?

Comment: Define "best placement". We can't know for sure what's really on your mind until you explain us in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible to get the dimensions of your images server-side? If so, you can do the following sorting and write out the original HTML in the desired order so that the page is actually loaded with the images in the correct place.*

In order to keep your page load from flickering all over the place, I would do the following.

Render your images off the page (e.g. left: -9999px) in a common container (assume `<div id="myImageContainer"></div>`)

Get all of the images... `var imageArray = document.getElementById("myImageContainer").getElementsByTagName("img");`

Sort your array based on `imageArray[i].offsetWidth` or something like that.

Insert your images into a new container where you actually want them displayed.

Comment: I felt this was a little hacky, as I was hoping for a more native way of doing things hoping there was a float option for it. But this did work and I'm happy with it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the "ImageLoader" utility I posted here:

[Resizing dynamic images not working more than one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169525/resizing-dynamic-images-not-working-more-than-one-time/4169595#4169595)

The problem is, images take time to load.  You can't sort them as you wish until you know the sizes of all the images.  But to get that, you (normally) need to wait for all the images to fully load.  However, that utility will make it easy for you to get the sizes of the images as soon as they are available, rather than waiting for the full images to load.

The alternative is to have something server side that will feed you the sizes of the images from the beginning, but in the absence of that I suggest either dropping in my utility, or modifying its logic to suit your need (i.e. start a timer that monitors each image for having a width and height).